# Find the number of polynomials satisfying the root conditions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $S$ be the set of all polynomials of the form $z^3+az^2+bz+c$, where $a$, $b$, and $c$ are integers. Find the number of polynomials in $S$ such that each of its roots $z$ satisfies either $\left\lvert z \right\rvert = 20$ or $\left\lvert z \right\rvert = 13$.

Obviously, I will do casework to break two cases:

> **C1**: $x_1, x_2 = \overline{x_1}$ are complex, and $x_3$ is real

And

> **C2**: $x_1, x_2, x_3 \in \mathbb{R}$, all real.

It is a bit difficult to do this problem, but I will begin by writing:

$P(z) = (z - x_1)(z - x_2)(z-x_3)$ is the root (cubic) form.

Suppose $|z_1| = 13$ then $|z_2| = 13$ and $z_3 = \pm 13, \pm 20.$

Since: $\sqrt{(-a)^2 + (-b)^2} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ there are $2$ choices for  each pair $(a, b)$ in $z_1, z_2$ and $4$ choices for $z_3$.

By vieta's formulas:

Let $z_1 = t + iy$:

> $2t + z_3 = -a$
>
> $z_3(t^2 + y^2) = -c$

It is possible to see from relation (1) that $t$ must be an integer and because of that $y$ be a integer too (in the second relation).

Back on topic,

Integers satisfying $t^2 + y^2 = 169$ are: $(t, y) = (\pm 12, \pm 5), (\pm 5, \pm 12), (0, \pm 13)$

Possible quadratics with this are:

$(z - (12 + 5i))(z - (12 - 5i))$ and $(z - (-12 + 5i))$ but then we get over counted,

the problem is the answer is a big value of $540$ somehow.

Answer (score 2):

I get 540; thanks to @mathlove for catching one of my errors.

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, choosing a polynomial is the same as choosing its roots (with multiplicity).  Let $A$ be the set $\{\pm13,\pm20\}$ of candidate real roots, and $B$ the set of candidate complex roots with strictly positive imaginary part.  The latter have the form $(a+i \sqrt b)/2$ where $a$ and $b>0$ are integers such that $(a^2+b)/4$ = $N^2$, where $N$ is $13$ or $20$. Once we choose $a$, we have $b=4N^2-a^2$, so $a$ can run from $-(2N-1)$ to $2N-1$, giving $4N-1$ possibilities for each $N$.  Hence $|B|=4(20)-1+4(13)-1=130$.

In case 1 we can select one root from list $A$ and one root from list $B$ (which determines the third root; there's no overcounting since the third root is not in list $B$).  Thus the number of solutions in case 1 is $|A|\,|B|$.  In case 2 we can select three roots from list $A$, with replacement, but order doesn't matter.  The number of ways to do this is $\binom{|A|+3-1}{3}$ (by "stars and bars," for example.)  So the total number of solutions is 
$$4\cdot 130 + \binom{6}{3} = 540.$$

Comment: As an example, the roots of $z^3+19z^2-380z-8000$ are $z=20,(-39\pm\sqrt{79}\ i)/2$. It seems that you don't count this polynomial.

Comment: @mathlove Oops. Fixed that, and counted the case 1 solutions correctly now.